# How to convert number into array of summands from predefined set?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is a set of constants: `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]`.

I have to input any natural number (positive integer) and output an array of its summands from the set above in descending order.
For example: `3497 => [512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 256, 128, 32, 8, 1]`.

How would I do that?
I can understand that recursive algorithm can handle the problem, but I'm not so good at recursion.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The summands should not be greater than `512` or what?

Comment: Constants will be the provided set of constants only or can it be set of any random nos???

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: The summands should be taken from the set.

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta: I don't understand you.

Comment: How about `Array(3497).fill(1);`?

Comment: Are the of constants fixed like this or do you want an answer to work with any set of constants..?

Comment: @Redu: For me fixed constant will be totally fine. But for other person this will be not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some recursive code that correctly find the summands from any set:

```js
function summands(n, values) {

    function s(n, found, values) {
        if (!n)
            return found;

        let t;
        values
            .filter(x => x <= n)
            .some((x, i) => t = s(n - x, found.concat(x), values.slice(i)));
        return t;
    }

    return s(n, [], values.sort((a, b) => b - a));
}

console.log(summands(6, [2, 5, 7]));
console.log(summands(6, [1, 5, 7]));
console.log(summands(3497, [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]));
```

and here's a generator that yields all possible combinations:

```js
function *summands(n, values) {

    function *s(n, found, values) {
        if (n == 0)
            yield found;

        for (let [i, x] of values.entries()) {
            if (x <= n)
                yield *s(n - x, found.concat(x), values.slice(i));
        }
    }

    yield *s(n, [], values.sort((a, b) => b - a));
}

for(let k of summands(8, [4,3,1])) {
    console.log(k.join())
}
```

Finally, if your operands are always powers of two, you can create a bit composition for a given number in a much faster way:

```js
function toBits(n, size) {
    var r = new Array(n >> size).fill(1 << size);
    while (size--)
        if (n & (1 << size))
            r.push(1 << size)
    return r;
}

console.log(toBits(3497, 9));
```

Comment: No need for assigning `values.sort(...)` to `values`

Comment: Why do you so like one-lettered variables? :)
Thank you, the latest option is highly efficient.

Answer (score 5):

For any values, you could use a combined approach with iterating and recursive call of a function with a dependent smaller set of values.

```js
function combine(array, sum) {

    function c(left, right, sum) {
        if (!sum) {
            result = right;
            return true;
        }
        return left.some(function (a, i, aa) {
            return a <= sum && c(aa.slice(i + (a > sum - a)), right.concat(a), sum - a);
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    c(array.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; }), [], sum);
    return result;
}

console.log(combine([2, 5, 7], 6));
console.log(combine([1, 5, 7], 6));
console.log(combine([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512], 3497));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How do you handle case like `number=6, values=[2, 5]`?

Comment: that is a question of combination.

Comment: @DanielCheng: `6 => [2, 2, 2]`

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky that's not why the above code will do though

Comment: @DanielCheng: Yep, now I see

Comment: @NinaScholz: Thanks for edit. Please consider several things: `result` should be 1D-array, not 2D; `array` is better to be optional (particularly in my case, those constants are fixed forever); and it is very difficult to read and understand a code with a plenty of one-lettered variables. But no offense, your answer is very useful.

Comment: what means *fixed forever*?

Comment: @NinaScholz: It means that in my case every time I call the function, the `array` is equal to the set from the OP above: `[1, 2, 4, 8 … ]`. So I will call it `convert(3497)` or `convert(1023)` etc.

Comment: then the old propsal works for you best ... i think. i can copy it to the actual one as well, i you like.

Comment: @NinaScholz: You decide. The current is the best.